# Is it possible to apply hover property based on width of a particular area?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

```js
function shrinkMenu(){
 document.getElementById("aside").className="aside-after-click";
 document.getElementById("main").className="main-after-click";
   var l= document.getElementsByClassName('hide-menu');
        for (var j = 0;j < l.length ; j++) {
            l[j].classList.add("hide-menu-after-click");
        }
}
```

```css
ul,li {
  list-style:none;
  }
#aside {
  float:left;
  /*width:220px;*/
  height:60px;
  background-color:red;
  }
.aside{
width:220px;
}

.aside-after-click{
width:60px;
}
#main {
  float:left;
  
  height:60px;
  background-color:green;
  }
.main{
  width:calc(100% - 220px);
}
.main-after-click{
  width:calc(100% - 60px);
}
#button{
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-left:10px;
  }
.hide-menu-after-click{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div id="aside" class="aside">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <i class = "fa fa-glass" > </i>
      <span class="hide-menu"> menu title1 </span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <i class = "fa fa-glass" > </i>
      <span class="hide-menu"> menu title2 </span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <i class = "fa fa-glass" > </i>
      <span class="hide-menu"> menu title3 </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="main" class="main">
  <button type="button" onclick="shrinkMenu();" id="button">shrink menu</button>
</div>
```

On the above code mainly we have two parts 1.aside 2.main. The aside part will shrink when we click on the button and also the menu title will hided.i need to be displayed the menu titles on hover on corresponding icon.is it possible to apply hover property based on width of a particular area(using @ media rule) ? or any other alternatives to solve this ?

**Note:** the hover property doesn't need to be work when the *aside* have width :220px (works only when width: 60px)

Comment: Not on width specific, but simply you can check width of particular area in your function and separate your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Here, using the `~` [general siblings CSS combinator](https://devdocs.io/css/general_sibling_selectors), together with `:hover` pseudoclass:

```js
function shrinkMenu() {
  document.getElementById("aside").className = "aside-after-click";
  document.getElementById("main").className = "main-after-click";
  var l = document.getElementsByClassName('hide-menu');
  for (var j = 0; j < l.length; j++) {
    l[j].classList.add("hide-menu-after-click");
  }
}
```

```css
ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
}
#aside {
  float: left;
  /*width:220px;*/
  height: 60px;
  background-color: red;
}
.aside {
  width: 220px;
}
.aside-after-click {
  width: 60px;
}
.aside-after-click:hover {
  width: 220px;
}
#main {
  float: left;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: green;
}
.main,
.aside-after-click:hover ~ .main-after-click {
  width: calc(100% - 220px);
}
.main-after-click {
  width: calc(100% - 60px);
}
#button {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.hide-menu-after-click {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div id="aside" class="aside">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <i class="fa fa-glass"> </i>
      <span class="hide-menu"> menu title1 </span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <i class="fa fa-glass"> </i>
      <span class="hide-menu"> menu title2 </span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <i class="fa fa-glass"> </i>
      <span class="hide-menu"> menu title3 </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="main" class="main">
  <button type="button" onclick="shrinkMenu();" id="button">shrink menu</button>
</div>
```